# Missing Explain Plan tab in SQuirreL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan, squirrel-sql

I seem to suddenly be missing the Explain Plan tab next to the Results tab in SQuirreL when logging on to Oracle. Does anybody know whether this could be due to a setting somewhere or a missing plugin?

I couldn't find an obvious option (or in fact any mention of explain plans in the "Getting Started" document or help page), it is just something that was working until now.

I have the plugins:

codecompletion, editextras, mysql, oracle, sqlval, syntax, don't think I have changed these for a while.

I connect using the "thin" JDBC driver.

Comment: The tab appears in **3.7** , but I also have a lot of plugins. However, they don't seem to influence it because the unloading don't make the tab to disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Looks related to the 3.6 release. Don't know yet if it's a bug or if there is some kind of new way of explaining plans...

I tried re-installing SquirreL SQL 3.5.1 and the Explain Plan tab was back.